# cannot call context.SetError from IAuthenticationTokenProvider

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, token, owin

I have a simple implementation of OAuth 2.0 by OWIN in my application supporting refresh tokens as well.

```
void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
```

In this method if the refresh token is not valid I want to call SetError (or something like that) to return the proper json response instead of default "invalid_grant", the context which is of type `AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext` does not seem to contain any such method. for now I'm just setting an empty ticket and in my `GrantRefreshToken` method I'm checking if the ticket contains any claims if not this means that refresh token is invalid and I'm setting error response from there like this

```
public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var claimCount = context.Ticket.Identity.Claims.Count();

        if (claimCount > 0)
            context.Validated(context.Ticket.Identity);
        else
            RejectWithJson(context, new GeneralError { ErrorCode = GeneralErrorCode.InvalidRefreshToken, Message = "Invalid refresh token" }, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    });
}
```

Is there any way to do this from `Receive` method ?

Comment: You ever figure this out? =[  "invalid_grant" is just not descriptive enough.